# Creating a Kubernetes deployment that contains Docker and Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to create a Kubernetes deployment that allows building Docker images and Jenkins on the same host. Here is my YAML configuration for the deployment containing Docker in Docker and Jenkins containers within the `jenkins-docker-in-docker` deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-docker-in-docker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-docker-in-docker
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-docker-in-docker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dind-daemon
          image: docker:18.01.0-dind
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 20m
              memory: 512Mi
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: docker-graph-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker
        - name: docker-cmds
          image: docker:18.01.0
          command: ['docker', 'run', '-p', '80:80', 'httpd:latest']
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 256Mi
          env:
            - name: DOCKER_HOST
              value: tcp://localhost:2375
        - name: ml-services
          image: trion/jenkins-docker-client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

With a simple Pipeline copied from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/ :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build I receive this error:

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . maven:3-alpine

    Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    [Pipeline] isUnix
    [Pipeline] sh
    + docker pull maven:3-alpine
    Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    ERROR: script returned exit code 1
    Finished: FAILURE
```

My understanding which now seems incorrect is that the containers `dind-daemon`, `docker-cmds` & `ml-services` containers exist within the same deployment, in this case named `jenkins-docker-in-docker`. Therefore, Docker and Jenkins should be available on `jenkins-docker-in-docker`?

Have I configured the Kubernetes file incorrectly?

Update:

I modified the yaml to set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable:

```
- name: ml-services
  env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: "dind-daemon:2375"
  image: trion/jenkins-docker-client
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

The error on Jenkins is now:

> - docker inspect -f . maven:3-alpine
>
> error during connect: Get
> http://dind-daemon:2375/v1.40/containers/maven:3-alpine/json: dial
> tcp: lookup dind-daemon on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host [Pipeline]
> isUnix [Pipeline] sh
>
> - docker pull maven:3-alpine error during connect: Post http://dind-daemon:2375/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=maven&tag=3-alpine:
>   dial tcp: lookup dind-daemon on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host
>   [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // withEnv [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node
>   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline ERROR: script returned exit code 1
>   Finished: FAILURE

Do I need to expose the docker daemon on 10.245.20.10:53 ?

Update 2:

With help from accepted answer I got this working using following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-docker-in-docker1.1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-docker-in-docker1.1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-docker-in-docker1.1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dind-daemon
          image: docker:18.01.0-dind
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 20m
              memory: 512Mi
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: docker-graph-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
        - name: docker-cmds
          image: docker:18.01.0
          command: ['docker', 'run', '-p', '80:80', 'httpd:latest']
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
              memory: 256Mi
          env:
            - name: DOCKER_HOST
              value: tcp://localhost:2375
        - name: ml-services
          env:
            - name: DOCKER_HOST
              value: tcp://localhost:2375
          image: trion/jenkins-docker-client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home

      volumes:
        - name: docker-graph-storage
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

I've likely included some redundant configuration in the above .yaml config, it executes a `Docker in Docker` container with `Jenkins` and successfully execute's the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker tries to use the unix socket to connect to the daemon.
This happens, when no DOCKER_HOST environment variable is set.

Use the correct host and port to connect to your docker daemon. In your setup it would be "dind-daemon".